# Can't assign to constant value Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know why I got this error

> Cannot assign to value: 'x' is a 'let' constant

with this code :

```
    func swap(x:AnyObject,y:AnyObject){
      let tmp = x
      x=y
      y=tmp
    }
```

Comment: [There is already a `Swift.swap` function](http://iswift.org/cookbook/swap-2-elements-in-array). Besides, your swap function does nothing since x and y are not inout.

Comment: I tryed to use swap but I'm not using variables of type 'inout'

Comment: `swap(list[index], y: list[index+1])`

Comment: @AxelLeBot Then probably you declared `list` with `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: @AxelLeBot The mutation to the parameter itself won't propagate out without using `inout`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function parameters are constants in Swift. In previous versions you could make them mutable by marking them with `var`, but this is going away in Swift 3.

If you want to actually swap the passed values, you have to declare them `inout`:

```
func swap(inout x: AnyObject, inout y: AnyObject) {
    let tmp = x
    x = y
    y = tmp
}
```

or just...

```
func swap(inout x: AnyObject, inout y: AnyObject) {
    (x, y) = (y, x)
}
```